# How to create a Binding that updates for every keypress of an NSTextField?

Tags: swift, cocoa

I wrote a custom NSView in Swift (to display a password strength) and made it KVC and KVO compatible.

I am binding the value of an NSTextField to the value of the custom NSView using:

```
textField.bind("value", to: strengthView, withKeyPath: "value", options: nil)
```

This works fine, except the binded value is only updated when I press enter or if the text field looses focus.

Question: is there an elegant way to make the binding update for every key-press in the NSTextField?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with the option for the binding `NSContinuouslyUpdatesValueBindingOption`.
You can get an overview for all the options on the [bindings options reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CocoaBindingsRef/Concepts/BindingsOptions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002304-BAJEAIEE) website.
The easiest way to test all the options for a control is to use the bindings in Interface Builder.

Comment: This works. Here is the requiered code in Swift3: `textField.bind("value", to: strengthView, withKeyPath: "value", options: [NSContinuouslyUpdatesValueBindingOption:true])`